# Jump to last stayed at position

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am aware that <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd> to move between `jumplist` as well as <kbd>g;</kbd> and <kbd>g,</kbd> to move between `changelist`

However, most of the time, points of interest are not exactly places that I jumped (my vim-fu is not advanced enough for me to jump exactly to the place I know I would be interested in) to or places that I edited, but rather, places that I spent quite some time studying

**Is there any way (vimscript / plugins) that allow me to jump to and forth between positions that I actually stayed at (e.g. longer than 1 second)?**

One hack I could think of is to do a quick edit and delete e.g. <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>BkSpc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to mark that position on my edit list, but I am hoping to find a neater solution.

Comment: Just FYI, you can do `m\`` instead of `ii<bs><esc>` to directly add the current location to the jumplist.

Comment: Even more explicitly, if I find a certain place important, I'll mark it permanently (`ma`, `mb`, usually don't need more marks than that).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the current position to the jumplist via `m'` or `` m` ``.

To add all places that you've stayed at for a longer time (`'updatetime'`; default is 4 seconds), you can use an `:autocmd` on `CursorHold`:

```
:autocmd CursorHold * normal! m'
```